# How to add one shape at a time based on user interaction-using JavaFx

Tags: java, shapes, javafx-11

I want to be able to display just one shape at a time based on user input of a number between 4 and 9. That is my button on click should display a shape with n sides based on n (number entered by user) I do not want to keep adding new shapes to the scene, I want to be able to entered another number, click submit and get a new shape displayed on its own. How can I achieve this...code snippet below:

```
button.setOnAction(e ->  { // Enclose the if/else statement block within a try/catch block  to catch all errors.
        try {
            
          int   num = Integer.parseInt(text.getText());
         
          if  (num ==4) 
          {
             Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();  // import the built rectangle class for Javafx app..
                                                                         // Set height, Width and X and Y axis.
              rect.setX(200);
              rect.setY(200);
              rect.setWidth(100);
              rect.setHeight(100);
              rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
              if (num % 2 == 0) {                        // Using if/else conditions set the fill colour.
                  rect.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
              }
              else {
                  rect.setFill(Color.GREEN);
              }
               root.getChildren().add(rect);
          }
            
              else if (num == 5) 
             {
                  // Create a an object for Polygon and sets five coordinates to make a pentagon.
                  
                  Polygon pentagon = new Polygon();
                  pentagon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[] {200.0, 50.0,400.0, 50.0,450.0, 150.0,400.0, 250.0,200.0, 250.0 });
                  pentagon.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                  
                // Using if/else conditions set the fill colour.
                 if (num % 2 == 0) {                        
                      pentagon.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
                  }
                  else {
                      pentagon.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                  }             
                 // add to root.
                   root.getChildren().add(pentagon);
                   
              
              }
          
              else if (num == 6) 
                 {
                      // Create a an object for Polygon and set six coordinates to make a Hexagon.
                      
                      Polygon hexagon = new Polygon();
                      hexagon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[] {200.0, 50.0,400.0, 50.0,450.0, 150.0,400.0, 250.0,200.0, 250.0,150.0, 150.0 });
                      hexagon.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                      
                    // Using if/else conditions set the fill colour.
                     if (num % 2 == 0) {                        
                          hexagon.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
                      }
                      else {
                          hexagon.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                      }             
                     // add to root.
                       root.getChildren().add(hexagon);
                  
                  }
          
              else if (num == 7) 
                 {
                      // Create a an object for Polygon and set seven coordinates to make a heptagon..
                      
                      Polygon heptagon = new Polygon();
                      heptagon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[] {200.0, 50.0,400.0, 50.0,450.0, 150.0,400.0, 250.0,200.0, 250.0, 250.0,200.0,150.0, 150.0,});
                      heptagon.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                      
                    // Using if/else conditions set the fill colour.
                     if (num % 2 == 0) {                        
                          heptagon.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
                      }
                      else {
                          heptagon.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                      }             
                     // add to root.
                       root.getChildren().add(heptagon);
                  
                  }
          
              else if (num == 8) 
                 {
                      // Create a an object for Polygon and sets five coordinates to make an octagon.
                      
                      Polygon octagon = new Polygon();
                      octagon.getPoints().addAll(new Double[] {200.0, 50.0,400.0, 50.0,450.0, 150.0,400.0, 250.0,200.0, 250.0, 250.0,200.0, 150.0, 200.0, 200.0, 250.0});
                      octagon.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                      
                    // Using if/else conditions set the fill colour.
                     if (num % 2 == 0) {                        
                          octagon.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
                      }
                      else {
                          octagon.setFill(Color.GREEN);
                      }             
                     // add to root.
                       root.getChildren().add(octagon);
                  
                  }
              else {
                    Alert error = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                    error.setHeaderText("Invalid input");
                    error.setContentText("Please enter only numbers between 4 and 9");
                    error.showAndWait();                              
                  
                  
              }
          
          }
             
          catch (NumberFormatException error) {
             
                Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                alert.setHeaderText("Invalid input");
                alert.setContentText("Please enter only numbers");
                alert.showAndWait();
        }
```

Comment: You can use `root.getChildren().remove(shape)` to remove the shape you want. You'll have to keep a reference to the current shape and delete ot when you're ready to replace it.

Comment: @Alias, I tried that already, but problem, I am having is where to place the root.getChildren.remove(shape) within my code. I mean where to place the reference without causing the program to crash

Comment: Try keeping a static `shape` to the top of your class where you declare your button `onaction` which refers to the current shape. You can have a conditional check if the the current shape isn't null before you evaluate which shape to generate and remove it if it isn't. Remember to set the static shape object to reference the new shape in your code for every shape you make.

Comment: @Alias ..many thanks, much appreciated.